# Angular UI mask remove placeholder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am using angular ui `mask` directive for a credit card field and its adding underscores for the placeholder. Is there a way not to show the placeholder?

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973660/angular-ui-mask-empty-placeholder

Answer (score 1):

You can find example in their [demo](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/mask/demo/index.html).

Just write what you want to `placeholder` attribute.

```
<input name="masked" ui-mask="{{y}}" ng-model="x" placeholder="Write a mask or click a button"
               class="input-large" style="vertical-align: top;">
```

Comment: i want the place holder to be empty

Comment: Then I guess, ui-mask is not what you're looking for. You can try with `<input type="number">` with `maxlength` attribute. In common case it's not good for user to not see the mask, because his input will be just corrupted with no obvious reason.

Comment: Adding the placeholder forces the value inside placeholder to be the $viewValue when it shouldnt be. I'm disappointed with this plugin because of that..

Answer (score 1):

Please try this once.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="accountNumber" ui-mask="9999 9999 9999 9999 999"  ui-mask-placeholder-char="space" />
</div>
```

Using  `ui-mask-placeholder-char="space"` , you can replace underscore by space.