# Angular UI mask empty placeholder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am using angular ui mask directive for a date field and its adding underscores for the placeholder. Is there a way to show nothing on the placeholder?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding that is a plugin issue I found this amazing library called ngMask:

https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask

Answer (score 3):

Please try this once.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="accountNumber" ui-mask="9999 9999 9999 9999 999"  ui-mask-placeholder-char="space" />
</div>
```

Using  `ui-mask-placeholder-char="space"` , you can get empty placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long standing bug (in my opinion) in the plugin. There's an outstanding PR that fixes the issue but I believe it's not being approved because the author didn't fix the tests: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/issues/181

I have broken the changes out into a custom version. Include as a directive in your project instead of using Bower to include the official version. Credit goes to: https://github.com/qwyzyx for the code updates. I've just taken the time to convert it over to coffeescript and document the changes.

You'll still have to include the 'ui.mask' module in your app just like the normal version on Github. Config as normal if desired.

https://gist.github.com/lstone/a952e169090dc3c64594

If you need to convert to JS: http://js2.coffee/

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if we prefer what the Library is providing.
So, I would suggest you to use

**ui-mask-placeholder-char="space"**

add this to your HTML and it will work just fine.